Unique Checks in Aggregates vs Database
I'm new to DDD and wondering what the best practice is to handle simple unique constraints.
My application allows for creation of an Item that is named by the user - and this name must be unique across all existing Items.
It makes little sense to me to fetch all Items from the database just to check for uniqueness in an Aggregate (which would be the only invariant). However, the database is not part of the Domain Model implementation, and outsourcing this invariant check seems like a breach to me.
So how should one combine these two worlds: Using the database's efficient capabilities, vs keeping an expressive Domain Model in the code that doesn't get watered down by external technologies?

First question: why? Who needs it to be unique? Is that a business decision, or is it to cover for a technical limitation (e.g. because you're using it as a key somewhere). Depending on whose decision it is, it should be implemented differently.

Is this a technical question (within i.e. SQL DBs)? Then I would suggest a unique constraint, either within a table, or add a shared table containing all reserved names. If it is about DDD? Then in my experience (at some point) there is no way around compromising for technical capabilities, no matter the stack you choose. Although you may able to add layers of abstraction to keep more true to your design in higher layers.


My application allows for creation of an Item that is named by the user - and this name must be unique across all existing Items.

Welcome to the world of set-validation.
So two warnings before you set off along this path.  First, make sure that you understand how important this uniqueness constraint is to the business (see Greg Young, 2010).  Second, be wary of trying to introduce such constraints on data that doesn't belong to you.  The world will quite happily ignore naive domain constraints, and if you are also unlucky then it will do so at the most expensive time for you.
In general: if you want to enforce some property of a set (meaning that you want to be able to forbid any changes to the set that would disturb the property), then you need to be able to lock (at least logically) the entire set.

It makes little sense to me to fetch all Items from the database just to check for uniqueness .... outsourcing this invariant check seems like a breach to me.

Yup - the tension there is real, and we get to make trade offs.
What you can sometimes do is redefine your set; in other words instead of ensuring that "Pat" is unique in the set of names, enforce instead the constraint that the set of items related to the name "Pat" has at most one element.
(Not that this approach may introduce other problems; trade offs, remember?)

That all said, if your current data storage appliance has the capabilities that you need already baked in, it's probably more cost effective, and healthier for your deadlines, to leverage the capabilities in your data store rather than inflicting some exotic ceremony on yourself just to unlock a domain driven design achievement.
(You should, perhaps, leave some breadcrumbs behind, so that future you understands the context of the decision that you are making, and that correct enforcement of uniqueness as required by the business constrains your choice of data appliance to one with the following capabilities....)

"Yup - the tension there is real, and we get to make trade offs." --- this frames the whole problem. Well said.

A Domain component and the Infrastructure component (DB) it relies on can be easily seen as completely separate from each other. It may, however, be helpful to consider the Infrastructure component to be an integral part of the domain one, meaning it comes to serve it.
From this perspective, it is OK to assume that any solution you come-up with for the uniqueness problem would and should involve DB capabilities.
This, in turn, does not suggest that business invariants (uniqueness in our case) cannot be expressed in app.

It makes little sense to me to fetch all Items from the database just to check for uniqueness in an Aggregate

Not that little sense. Some DB aspects may serve that "fetching all items" requirement. If, for example, your DB lets you have the name-field indexed, then your app can execute a performant query to find if name already exists (prior to item creation), and throw a domain-error if exists indeed.
Another solution would be to create a unique constraint of name-field (assuming DB-support for that), and have app intercepting DB exception caused by uniqueness violation during create-operation (then of course throwing a domain-error).

I think it would be a good compromise to add a method to the Entity's Repository that checks if name 'xyz' already exists. from my understanding, a Repo is part of the Domain Model and can be used in an Aggregate. this way I don't have to catch some proprietary DB exception in the application layer to implement Domain Logic.

Indeed the notion of Repo is part of domain, therefore it may define a method such as DoesNameExist(name). Implementation belongs to Infra (run query against table T from storage S where field F equals name). I do not see that as a compromise.
I would prefer not to use Repos inside Aggregates, but rather have a domain service for that logic.
As for DB exceptions, they should be translated into domain exceptions inside Repo (Infra), similar to how you translate DTOs into domain entities. Whether to check uniqueness by Repo-method (ahead) or by trapping a DB exception is a matter of taste.
